# Reporting Service Expression, how to get Customer.Company.Name?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am new to Reporting service, I have the following class

```
class Customer
{
   public Company Company {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Company has a Name property.  Given that Report datasource is List.  How to put the Company.Name in textBox?

That did not work =Fields!Company.Value.Name_ar.Value

Thanks

Comment: how about just _Fields!Name.Value_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I was not understanding the syntax of Expressions.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252095%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

To make it works, remove the last Value from the experssion, and make it
=Fields!Company.Value.Name_ar